# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code

```
d1={'key1':[1,2,3],'key2':[4,5,6]}
d1['key2'][0][2]
```

which produces this error:

> TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

I want the output to be `4,6`

Comment: `d1['key2'][0]` return `4`, and you cannot subscript `int`, ergo the mentioned error

Comment: Hi han Solo. Thanks for answering. Can you please explain what is meant by you cant subscript int.

Answer (score 1):

You are using subscription operation on a list item which is an integer (4 in this case), hence the error.

You can get your desired output using list slicing:

```
In [193]: d1 = {'key1': [1,2,3], 'key2': [4,5,6]}
In [194]: d1['key2']
Out[194]: [4, 5, 6]

In [195]: d1['key2'][0::2]  # [start:stop:step]
Out[195]: [4, 6]
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I am getting different idea. d1['key2'][0:3] also works fine.

Comment: @VIgneshNagaraj No, that won't work; `d1['key2'][0:3]` on current example will get you `[4]`.

Comment: But that worked.Can you please check it